# UnsatisfiedLinkError while building Tensorflow Lite demo source code

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

I am using Android Studio 3.0.3 with Gradle 3.3 and I was trying to build:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo

But I was troubled by this issue:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.createErrorReporter(int) (tried Java_org_tensorflow_lite_NativeInterpreterWrapper_createErrorReporter and Java_org_tensorflow_lite_NativeInterpreterWrapper_createErrorReporter__I)
 at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.createErrorReporter(Native Method)
 at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.<init>(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:47)
 at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.<init>(Interpreter.java:77)
 at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.ImageClassifier.<init>(ImageClassifier.java:94)
 at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.Camera2BasicFragment.onActivityCreated(Camera2BasicFragment.java:299)
 at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2620)
 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1296)
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve the problem?

Comment: No....Seems to be a knowledge desert here.

Comment: problem solved for you?

What is the tensor flow library version you are using ?

Answer (score 3):

Following Dharma's workaround, I changed:

From:

```
compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
```

To:

```
compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.1'
```

But the project would not build due to Gradle errors. In Android studio, I did the following:

File -> Project Settings -> Project
From:
`Gradle Version: 4.4, Android Plugin Version: 3.1.0`
To:
`Gradle Version: 4.1, Android Plugin Version: 3.0.0`

[Screenshot of Android Studio Project Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edjsu.png)

Those settings are based on the following document that lists all the correct combinations:
[Table of Plugin & Gradle Versions](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html)

With these settings, I'm able to build and run the sample projects without any problems...

Answer (score 1):

`@Jin Yifei,` I also ran into this same problem. I was able to work around it by rolling back the tensorflow-lite version to `0.1`. As far as I can tell the demo doesn't seem to be compatible with `0.1.1` (which is currently the latest).

You can do so by changing `app/build.gradle` from :

```
compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
```

to this :

```
compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case，it's because i choose the abifilters as armeabi :

```
defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi'        }
    }
```

.But the TFLite official [website](https://tensorflow.google.cn/lite/guide/android) says TFLite only support armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a.